# how to get a callback refresh function after alert is displayed?

Tags: jquery, callback, refresh, alert

I am try to make this simple password function in jquery work as I need it to. Right now, on page load, you are prompted to enter a password to see the body of the page. If the password is incorrect, you get an alert that it is wrong. That all works but it is dead from there.

What I need is a button to "try again" in the alert which simply refreshes the page so that you can try again.  How do I do this?  Perhaps someone has a solution that would work?

I **cant use js fiddle properly with this type of task** since you wouldn't be able to see the code if pass is incorrect (therefore not seeing my issue). So, I must paste all code here. I hope that is ok.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>-</title>
</head>
<body style="display:none;color: #000;">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/Javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
var password
var pass1="123"
password=prompt('Please enter password to view page')
if (password==123)
{ $('body').show(); }
else{
  alert('password incorrect! Try Again!')
}
});
</script> 
This is the page content that was password protected
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to refresh the page? Use a loop:

```
var correct_pass = false;

while (!correct_pass) {
    var pass1 = '123';
    var password = prompt('Please enter password to view page');

    if (password == pass1) {
        $('body').show();
        correct_pass = true;
    } else {
        alert('password incorrect! Try Again!');
    }
}
```

You could expand this into a function to make it a little more capable, say, so it won't bug the user with two popups in a row if they type their pass wrong:

```
(function get_password(prev_bad_pass = false) {
    if (prev_bad_pass) {
        var prompt_text = 'Password incorrect! Try Again!';
    } else {
        var prompt_text = 'Please enter password to view page';
    }

    var pass1 = '123';
    var password = prompt(prompt_text);

    if (password == pass1) {
        $('body').show();
    } else {
        get_password(true);   //run the function again
    }
}());
```

This function will execute over and over until the correct password is typed. You can certainly do it in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v2fmA/

Comment: Thank you so much! Im starting to learn jquery and never utilized  get_password(true);  So simple! Thanks again.

Comment: @DC1 that's called a recursive function. they're fun!